# Extract text from python list item

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've a python list whose items are as below, I want to extract only the text and remove the 0 and space from the item.

```
  [['0    Client Name:'],
  ['0    Client ID:'],
  ['0    Industry:'],
  ['0    SEC:'],
  ['0    Industry Sector:']]
```

So, how to extract only the text from each item?
This list was the result of the following loop:

```
   '''for index,row in df.iterrows():
        if index==0:
            continue
        elif index%2!=0:
            title.append(row.to_string().split(","))'''
```

Comment: arr[i].split()[1] will give you the word part of each sub-list

Answer (score 1):

new version of my last attempt:

```
import re

a = [['0    Client Name:'],
     ['0    Client ID:'],
     ['0    Industry:'],
     ['0    SEC:'],
     ['0    Industry Sector:']]

for i in range(len(a)):

    b = a[i][0]
    b = b.split('   ')
    
    print(b[1])
```

output:

```
 Client Name:
 Client ID:
 Industry:
 SEC:
 Industry Sector:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, altough not very clean but gets the job done.

```
l = [['0    Client Name:'],
    ['0    Client ID:'],
    ['0    Industry:'],
    ['0    SEC:'],
    ['0    Industry Sector:']]

newl = []

for i in range(len(l)):
    newl.append(l[i][0].split("  ")[2])

print(newl)
'''
['Client Name:', 'Client ID:', 'Industry:', 'SEC:', 'Industry Sector:']
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is `l`, then `[x[0][5:] for x in l]` removes the first 5 characters of each element of the list.